# Involutions in which all transpositions have the same distance

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups, involutions

I am wondering whether there exist a name in the literature for the following special type of permutation $\pi$ over $\{1, \dots n\}$.  $\pi$ is an involution, i.e., it is composed of nonoverlapping transpositions $(a_i, b_i)$.  Now, also the distance between the end-points in each transposition should be the same, i.e., $|a_i - b_i| = k$ for all $i$ for some $k$.

Comment: It depends on your purposes. If you just need a name for a secondary concept, it's probably not worth expending much effort to find a suitably evocative term, just something distinctive, such as "(multi-)toggle". If these permutations are your central objects of study, however, readers will welcome a short, memorable term that evokes a visual image closely related to your mathematical aims, e.g.,"track swap" (the ends of railroad ties representing the $a_{i}$ and $b_{i}$, and railroad tracks suggesting constant distance...something like that).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thanks for your comment. My question was a bit unclear. I was wondering whether there exist a name in the literature. But if not, these are good suggestions for names to use.